# Plugin won't be translated

Tags: wordpress, translation

I've installed a calendar plugin (called Calendar, by Kieran O'Shea) and I'm having trouble with the translation.

In the plugin folder (which doesn't have any sub folders) there's a file called *calendar.pot* which I've translated with poEdit. What I've tried is to edit the file and save it (i.e. not create a .po and .mo file), create a .po and .mo file (e.g. *calenderar.po*) and put in the root and I've even tried to create a folder called *language* and put the files in there.

Nothing works.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So, you didn't name it like `calendar-en_GB.po/.mo`? Any link to the plugin's source code?

Comment: Changing to "calendar-sv_SE" did the trick! Thanks"

Answer (score 0):

Supposing `WPLANG` is defined as `pt_BR`, the plugin and theme translations should have it appended to the `.mo/.po` files.

Copy the `calendar.pot` to `calendar-pt_BR.po`, open in PoEdit, translate and save. It will generate the `.mo` on save.